# RCTLinkingManager error when running React Native app on iOS emulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have developed a React Native app that is functioning correctly on Android, and now I need to publish it on iOS. After running the build process, everything appears to be working fine. However, when I try to open the app in the iOS emulator, I encounter the following error message:

"Attempted to remove more RCTLinkingManager listeners than added."

I have searched the internet for a solution to this problem, but most of the information I found pertains to issues with an AWS library that I am not using in my project. I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this error.

Here are the steps I have already taken:

> Cleared the cache of the Metro Bundler using the command npx react-native start --reset-cache.
> Cleaned the Xcode build folder by navigating to "Product" -> "Clean Build Folder" in Xcode.
> Verified the dependencies and ensured they are up to date and compatible with my current React Native version.
> Checked the permissions in the Info.plist file to confirm that the RCTLinkingManager module has the appropriate entries.
> Verified the build settings in Xcode to ensure that the necessary paths and references are correctly configured, and all required libraries and frameworks are included in the project.
> Reinstalled the project dependencies by executing the commands rm -rf node_modules, npm install, and cd ios && pod install && cd ...
> Despite these attempts, the error still persists.

Here is the phone log:

```
Attempted to remove more RCTLinkingManager listeners than added

-[RCTEventEmitter removeListeners:]
    RCTEventEmitter.m:107
__invoking___
-[NSInvocation invoke]
-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_drain
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
-[UIApplication _run]
UIApplicationMain
main
start_sim
0x0
0x0
```

Here is the Metro log:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo from /Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/index.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
     |                                       ^
  14 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
  15 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
  16 | import typeof CheckBox from './Libraries/Components/CheckBox/CheckBox';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:271:42)
    at resolve (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:571:33)
    at /Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:587:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:586:33)
    at /Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
Error: Unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo from /Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/react-native/index.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  11 | 'use strict';
  12 |
> 13 | import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
     |                                       ^
  14 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
  15 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
  16 | import typeof CheckBox from './Libraries/Components/CheckBox/CheckBox';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:271:42)
    at resolve (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:571:33)
    at /Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:587:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:586:33)
    at /Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/User/Documents/MyApp/test/MyApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
[Wed Jul 12 2023 16:43:08.171]  WARN     Require cycle: src/components/others/ModalFee/index.tsx -> src/components/others/ModalFee/OrderFees/index.tsx -> src/components/others/ModalFee/index.tsx

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Jul 12 2023 16:43:08.171]  WARN     Require cycle: src/components/others/ModalFee/index.tsx -> src/components/others/ModalFee/RemoveFee/index.tsx -> src/components/others/ModalFee/index.tsx

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
[Wed Jul 12 2023 16:43:08.172]  LOG      Running "MyApp" with {"rootTag":21,"initialProps":{}}
[Wed Jul 12 2023 16:43:08.173]  ERROR    Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[70,70,70,70,70,70,70,53,53,0,0,0,66],[3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,1,3,1,0,5],[["didSendNetworkData"],["didReceiveNetworkResponse"],["didReceiveNetworkData"],["didReceiveNetworkIncrementalData"],["didReceiveNetworkDataProgress"],["didCompleteNetworkResponse"],[8,2000,1689190988147,false],[8],[["permissions"],1357],[[["permissions","{\"writeExternalStorage\":true}"]],1359],[["user"],1361],["url"]],669]

This error is located at:
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainerInner) (at StackNavigator.tsx:63)
    in StackNavigator (at routes/index.tsx:48)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainerInner) (at routes/index.tsx:44)
    in Routes (at App.tsx:54)
    in PaymentProvider (at App.tsx:53)
    in AccountProvider (at App.tsx:52)
    in AuthProvider (at App.tsx:51)
    in OrderProvider (at App.tsx:50)
    in ProductsProvider (at App.tsx:49)
    in UserProvider (at App.tsx:48)
    in ToastProvider (at App.tsx:46)
    in SettingsProvider (at App.tsx:45)
    in FeeProvider (at App.tsx:44)
    in ModalDialogCmp (at App.tsx:43)
    in AccountProvider (at AppDemo.tsx:11)
    in OrderDemoProvider (at AppDemo.tsx:10)
    in DemonstrationProvider (at AppDemo.tsx:9)
    in AppDemo (at App.tsx:42)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:51)
    in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at App.tsx:33)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
[Wed Jul 12 2023 16:43:08.174]  ERROR    Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.

[[70,70,70,70,70,70,70,53,53,0,0,0,66],[3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,1,3,1,0,5],[["didSendNetworkData"],["didReceiveNetworkResponse"],["didReceiveNetworkData"],["didReceiveNetworkIncrementalData"],["didReceiveNetworkDataProgress"],["didCompleteNetworkResponse"],[8,2000,1689190988147,false],[8],[["permissions"],1357],[[["permissions","{\"writeExternalStorage\":true}"]],1359],[["user"],1361],["url"]],669]

This error is located at:
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainerInner) (at StackNavigator.tsx:63)
    in StackNavigator (at routes/index.tsx:48)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainerInner) (at routes/index.tsx:44)
    in Routes (at App.tsx:54)
    in PaymentProvider (at App.tsx:53)
    in AccountProvider (at App.tsx:52)
    in AuthProvider (at App.tsx:51)
    in OrderProvider (at App.tsx:50)
    in ProductsProvider (at App.tsx:49)
    in UserProvider (at App.tsx:48)
    in ToastProvider (at App.tsx:46)
    in SettingsProvider (at App.tsx:45)
    in FeeProvider (at App.tsx:44)
    in ModalDialogCmp (at App.tsx:43)
    in AccountProvider (at AppDemo.tsx:11)
    in OrderDemoProvider (at AppDemo.tsx:10)
    in DemonstrationProvider (at AppDemo.tsx:9)
    in AppDemo (at App.tsx:42)
    in RCTSafeAreaView (at SafeAreaView.js:51)
    in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at App.tsx:33)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
[Wed Jul 12 2023 16:43:09.117]  LOG      Unable to symbolicate stack trace: The stack is null
[Wed Jul 12 2023 16:43:09.120]  LOG      Unable to symbolicate stack trace: The stack is null
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "echo DEVICE=1 > .env && react-native run-android",   
    "android-clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest --watch --coverage=false",
    "test-final": "jest",

  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx, ts, tsx}": []
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.5",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "^7.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^7.1.7",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@types/events": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.17.2",
    "remask": "^1.2.2",
    "rn-tooltip": "^3.0.3",
    "typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vanilla-masker": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.16.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.34",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.7",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "^27.3.1",
    "lint-staged": "^12.0.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/models/**",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/babel.config.js/**"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.9"
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue specifically related to the RCTLinkingManager error in my React Native app on iOS.